# Mensagem no Google Webmasters Tools - Changes to sitelinks for http://meusite.com.br

Tags: aplicação-web, google

Alguém sabe o que significa essa mensagem no Google WebMasters Tools, estou recebendo ela direto.
Só sei que é algo a ver com SiteLinks, Acredito que seja alguma falha ou erro.

> A verified user has blocked or unblocked sitelinks for this site: http://meusite.com.br/.
>   The links shown below some sites in our search results, called sitelinks, are meant to help users navigate your site. Our systems analyze the link structure of your site to find shortcuts that will save users time and allow them to quickly find the information they're looking for. The process of creating Sitelinks is completely automated, but if you think that the sitelinks displayed for your site are inappropriate or incorrect, you can block them so that they no longer appear. More information.

Answer (score 1):

### [Fonte: Suporte do Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=pt)

### Sitelinks

```
Os links exibidos abaixo de alguns resultados da pesquisa do Google, 
chamados de sitelinks, têm como finalidade ajudar os usuários a navegar 
em seu site. Nossos sistemas analisam a estrutura de links de seu site 
a fim de localizar atalhos para poupar o tempo do usuário e possibilitar
a localização rápida da informação que está procurando.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
*1: o principal resultado de pesquisa*

*2: inks de sites*

Exibimos links de sites nos resultados somente quando achamos que eles 
podem ser úteis para o usuário. Se a estrutura de seu site não permitir 
que nossos algoritmos localizem bons links de site ou se você achar que 
os links para seu site não são pertinentes para a consulta do usuário, 
nós não os exibiremos.
```

---

Resumindo, o `Google` automaticamente vai gerando esses `sitelinks` pra facilitar a experiência do usuário ao querer acessar uma página ou buscar algo em seu site, as vezes isso não da muito certo e tu pode remover eles. No link no topo da resposta tem mais detalhes de como você faz para remover isso.

Se ainda não ficou claro o que são os `sitelinks`, veja um exemplo do próprio Google:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ok, até conheço essa função SiteLink, só gostaria de entender a mensagem que chegou. Se não estou errado parece ser alguma chamada para alguma falha que esteja ocorrendo. não entendi a mensagem. E se for alguma falha, oque fazer para corrigir.

Comment: @LenoSousa Existe outro `WebMaster` que controla o site junto com você? Normalmente esse aviso é quando alguém altera os sitelinks

Comment: Não, somente eu.

Comment: Pode ser que quando a própria ferramenta do Google altere seus sitelinks você seja notificado, dê uma olhada.